# How can I get to the admin of a Google+ Page?

Tags: google-plus, google-plus-pages

I created a Google+ Page and filled it up with placeholder info until I get the content ready. Now I've logged in again as me.

How can I get back to the Page admin again?

Facebook has this feature somewhere in the menus/options, where you can switch between your normal account and your Page. I can't seem to find anything to activate it on Google Plus.

Is there an easy way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under you name in Google+, you'll see a page menu (drop down), click on the arrow to see a list of your pages; click on a page to manage that page.

For more information, see http://www.google.com/+/business/